# Auto pushing to a specific folder on GitHub or other Git service

Tags: git, github

The Situation:
I have one Git Repo with files; let's call it "Robot". When I commit to Robot, I want something to auto-commit my new commit to another big repo under a specific folder.

The Problem:
I don't know how to do it. I know GitLab has mirror repository, but it mirrors the whole repo and it won't do it to a specific folder.

EDIT:

Here's an analogy:
The big repo is like a CDN and Robot is a framework.

Comment: Is the "another big repo" a subfolder of Robot? What's the relationship between the two? Are files from Robot publishing into the other repo?

Comment: No, the big repo is kind of like a CDN, and robot is a framework.

Comment: @nvioli no solution?

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two ways to mirror a repository to multiple locations:

- client side (push to two repositories at once)
- server side (only push to a single *serverA*, and let the server forward the push to another *serverB*)

#### client side

If you are mainly working from a single working copy (that is: you only clone the respository to a single machine; and do all the work there), and bandwidth is not an issue (and since git mostly deals with sourcecode that should be true in most circumstances), the simplest way is to just add two (2) `remote`s to your working copy (or copies):

```
 git clone uri://serverA/myrepo.git
 cd myrepo
 git remote set-url --add --push origin uri://serverB/robot.git
 git push
```

The only drawback here is, that whenever you clone anew, you have to setup the additional push-url.

See also [Git - Pushing code to two remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113)

#### server side

You can also deploy a server-side `post-receive` hook, that will just calls `git push` to another server.

1. create the repository on serverB: `uri://serverB/robot.git`
2. create a bare repository on the serverA

   ```
   git create --bare myrepo.git
   ```
3. add a remote to the bare repository

   ```
   git remote add origin uri://serverB/robot.git
   ```
4. add a `post-receive` hook to the bare repository on *serverA*

   ```
   $ cat > myrepo.git/hooks/post-receive << EOF
   git push --all
   git push --tags
   EOF
   ```
5. on your desktop, clone `uri://serverA/myrepo.git`, add files and push them.

   the files get automatically forwarded, provided that the user which runs the git-hook on the server is actually allowed to push to serverB.

I find this favourable if multiple working copies and multiple users are involved.
There are two issues though:

1. you need to be able to create `post-receive` hooks on the server. This usually means that you must have administrative access to the server (e.g. be able to `ssh` into it; or have other super-cow powers).
   This rules out `github` as your *serverA*.
2. in virtually all cases you must **authenticate** to the *serverB*.
   E.g. you can use password-less `ssh-keys` (stored on the server) for this.
   (github allows you to add `Deploy Keys` with write-access to each repository).

See also [Git push to one remote repo which deploys to multiple other remote repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869816/)

Comment: again, this mirrors robot to the other repo.

Comment: i want robot to be mirrored to a specific folder in the big repo